# Change Searchview focus color

Tags: android, search, themes, searchview

I want to change the searchview color on selection/focus.

I am using ActionBarSherlock with default theme. I tried changing theme but didn't have any luck there.

Here's an image in which searchview focus color is yellow:

[image: searchview with yellow focus color]

How can I change it to transparent?